# SolrCore Initialization Failure Error loading class 'solr.IntField'

Tags: solr

I have a strange problem, I'm trying to move an existing and working configuration of Apache Solr from a server to another one.

The configuration is really simple since it's still incomplete, i've just create the core and create a managed-schema.

The instance is running flawlessy on the former server, but on the new one, with the exactly same configutation, gives an Initialitation Error.

```
corename: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core corename: Can't load schema /opt/solr/server/solr/corename/conf/managed-schema: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "int": Error loading class 'solr.IntField'
```

Please check your logs for more information

I've read somewhere else that the IntField types are deprecated, and TrieIntField should be used instead, but I Believe that even TrieIntField is deprecated, the schema contains the same fields on both server with the same version of Solr, but one works, the other one doesn't!

Can someone gives me a hint? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should replace solr.IntField with solr.TrieIntField

Please refer the link [changes in solr](http://www.sitecorevarun.com/2015/07/solr-error-plugin-init-failure-for.html)

The IntField is depricated along with some other fields.